# Oracle: DML operation inside a query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I'm getting this error:

```
cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
```

when i tried to execute the query

```
select st_atten_up(1,7) from dual;
```

the code has given below.

```
create or replace FUNCTION st_atten_up(stu_id IN student_info.id%type,app_mon IN student_attendence.month%type) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
att1 NUMBER;
BEGIN SELECT ATTENDANCE into att1 FROM student_attendence 
WHERE student_attendence.id = stu_id and student_attendence.month = app_mon; 
att1 := att1 + 1;
UPDATE student_attendence SET ATTENDANCE = att1 
where id = stu_id and month = app_mon;
return att1;
END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `pragma autonomous_transaction;` inside your function to make it callable from `select` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can technically execute DML inside a select if the function called has been declared as `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` ([Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm)). However, it's **rarely** a good idea to execute DML from within a `SELECT` statement for a number of good reasons (including mutating tables, performance degradation.) But, to answer your question, you can write your function with the `PRAGMA`:

```
create or replace FUNCTION st_atten_up(stu_id IN student_info.id%type,app_mon IN student_attendence.month%type) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
att1 NUMBER;
BEGIN SELECT ATTENDANCE into att1 FROM student_attendence 
WHERE student_attendence.id = stu_id and student_attendence.month = app_mon; 
att1 := att1 + 1;
UPDATE student_attendence SET ATTENDANCE = att1 
where id = stu_id and month = app_mon;
return att1;
END;
```

Comment: Substitute rarely for never... call the function multiple times in a SQL statement and what happens? The student ends up with 150% attendance...

Comment: @wolf thanks it's working. Just i need to add "commit" to prevent the 
>>ORA-06519:Active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back :

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call a function in DML  if the function in itself is having a DML operation.

Here you would be trying to call the function in SELECT/UPDATE.. and thats why its giving the error. If you want to do so please create a procedure.